# How do you create a Materalise checkbox which looks like a button

Tags: css, materialize

I'm using Materalise UI and I'm interested in creating a number of toggled buttons like the following: -

---

[image]

---

I did a bit of googling but found nothing.  Some people are suggesting creating `<input type="checkbox" ... />` + `<label>...</label>` pairs and making the checkbox invisible.  I had a blast at that it worked really badly with Materalise UI.

Maybe there is a much easier solution?  Any hints / advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script takes care of checking the checkboxes and styling the labels. Materialize is a bit special :). Also note you want to remove `.btn-flat` from any label of a `:checked` checkbox on intial render of the page (in case you have some of them checked by default or based on user data).

```js
$('label.btn').on('click','input', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).attr('checked', !$(this).attr('checked'));
  $(e.target).closest('label').toggleClass('btn-flat');
});
```

```css
label.btn:not(.btn-flat) { 
  background-color: #35DDE0;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<label class="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-flat">
  <input type="checkbox" name="countries[]" value="african" />African</label>
<label class="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-flat">
  <input type="checkbox" name="countries[]" value="british" />British</label>
<label class="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-flat">
  <input type="checkbox" name="countries[]" value="french" />French</label>
<label class="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-flat">
  <input type="checkbox" name="countries[]" value="german" />German</label>
```

Comment: Pretty much perfect.  One small question though - how do I override the selected background color to be blue `#35DDE0` (instead of the green colour)?

Comment: Either by CSS (see answer update) or by using their [`built-in color classes`](http://materializecss.com/color.html#palette) - you'd have to apply them on the buttons, besides `btn`, or by using [`sass`](http://materializecss.com/color.html#sass) variables to change the primary color in the entire app/website.

Comment: Thanks mate, really appreciate your time!